# JQuery Masonry doesn't refresh the container height

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Using Jquery Masonry which works fine.
However i have small problem.
Layout looks like:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

After the masonry is initialized  after page is loaded with:

```
$('.container').masonry ( {        
    itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

i'm trying to use Ajax call to replace the boxes with some other.
before ajax im using:

```
$('.container').masonry( 'remove', $('.container .box'));
```

and after it is loaded :

```
$('.container').prepend(data).masonry( 'appended', data );
```

it loads all new boxes and auto positione it with masonry but it also leaves a big gap on the top of the container. New boxes are added not at the top of the container but exactly in the same position where removed boxes ended. 
I was trying to use some masonry functions like reloadItems, layout etc but nothing helps :(
Anyone knows the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing two opposite methods - prepend and append. It seems that Masonry needs to know exactly on which side your adding your elements. Take a look at the docs example:

http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#prepended

At first hit lets just try to change your code to:

```
$('.container').prepend(data).masonry( 'prepended', data );
```

Comment: Thanks for help. i've changed to your code and now I have the gap but at the bottom of all boxes. It seems like Masonry thinks that there are still some boxes and is calculating the height of the container as if they were still there, even if they are not displayed. I was trying to manually set the hight of the conteiner but it doesnt help

Comment: Do you have it online somewhere? I can't get my head around the problem without touching it.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, my solution was to:

1 Remove the original items.

2 Remove the masonry functionality on the element.

3 Re-initialize the masonry functionality on the element.

4 Then add the new items using prepend.

```
//These were defined globally.
var masonryOptions = {
   columnWidth: 450,
   itemSelector: '.feature-block',
   gutter: 20
};

$grid = $('.masonry-grid').masonry(masonryOptions);

function clear() {
   $grid.masonry('remove', $grid.find('.feature-block'));
   $grid.masonry('destroy');
   $grid = $('.masonry-grid').masonry(masonryOptions);
}
```